# Send a USSD code to a designated stand alone USSD server

Tags: android, ussd

Is is possible to send a USSD code to a stand alone USSD server (A non-mobile carrier server) 
from Android device?

Specifically the scenario is:
A calls B
B has an app that can identify incoming calls
B send (through the app) USSD code to a USSD server that includes A caller ID
The server sends an email to A.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why not.

The USSD Server must be accessible, deployed on the internet.

Further details would be regarding the protocol used by the Service, it would be something like SOAP or XML over Sockets.